# How to calculate iOS app boot time

Tags: ios, nsdate

I was wondering if there is a quick and efficient way to determine the Time from opening an app to when it's fully loaded.

- I was thinking I'd do something like get an `NSDate` object in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and get another in my `UIViewController`, then compare them.
- However, I'm not sure that would be completely accurate. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really won't work because it doesn't deal with iOS loading and launching your app.

The best you should do is log a timestamp in `main` but again, this won't include the time it takes iOS to load and launch the app to the point that `main` is called.

Any timing you do will be from that point forward which may still be useful depending on your goal.

Comment: my goal is analytics. the company im writing the app for wants to know the load time for the app

Comment: The best you can do is from `main` to your root view controller being visible to the user.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you have a feeling for how much of this iOS overhead is related to the specifics of the application? I mean, is it a fixed cost with nothing to do with the app itself, or is it highly dependent on the size of the app, or something in between?

Comment: I don't know if the size of the app affects load time. It's certainly possible.

Comment: a lot of my apps have some loading stuff in between. injections and stuff. accepting notifications, setting up tables, analytics, retrieving data from servers about current users, that kind of thing. so that should all be factored in, because the app doesnt come to a complete "resting state" until that's all completed. the value i was looking for was from app selection on the home screen to resting state

Answer (score 0):

Keep a NSUserDefaults value to count the run time of the app in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or applicationDidBecomeActive method:

```
int i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"usageCount"];
i = i+1;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i forKey:@"usageCount"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```